# Pandas dataframe apply function returning new columns results in scalar error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a simple apply function for a Pandas dataframe which should return new column values but instead the following error message is returned:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Code:

```
valador = pd.DataFrame({'Region': [1, 2], 'Enemies': [3, 4], 'Weapons': [2, 3]})
def add_attributes():
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Region": [1], "Enemies": [1], "Weapons": [1]})
    return(df)
valador = valador.apply(lambda z: add_attributes(), axis=0)
```

Basically, I want to give the internal function some parameters which are not part of the dataframe and then do some calculations with them. Finally on basis of these calculations I want to get updated columns back to the dataframe. How can this be done with one apply function?

Comment: Please check your code is compilable for a [mcve]. Python does not use `//` for comments, `pd.DataFrame()` should be properly closed, and all variables should be assigned. What is *all_data*, *train_data*, *labels*?

Comment: Updated. So can this be somehow vectorized?